# Registration form AJAX check for existing username (simple version)

Tags: ajax, forms, user-registration

I know they are already many questions related to this topic but I was looking for a simple way to make an ajax check for an existing username. So basically I have the HTML form and two functions (in function.php) - one to make the ajax request and the other to make the DB lookup. Note: I'm using WP Multisite.

**The HTML Form:**

```
<form method="post" name="register_user">
  <p> 
    <label for="register_name">Name<br> 
    <input type="text" name="register_name" placeholder="Enter your user name"> 
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="register_email">E-Mail<br> 
    <input type="text" name="register_email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail"> 
    </label>
  </p>
  <p> 
    <label for="register_pass">Password<br> 
    <input type="text" name="register_pass" placeholder="• • • • • • •"> 
    </label>
  <p> 
    <input class="button-large register" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </p>

</form>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
function mpl_add_js_login(){
?>

    <script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        $('input[name="register_name"]').change(function (e) {
            var this_field = $(this);
            var user_name = this_field.val();
            $('.uname_status').remove();
            $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                type: "POST",
                data: {'action': 'check_username', user_name: user_name},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                        this_field.closest('label').append('<div class="uname_status '+ response.text +'">'+response.text+'</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    });



    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('login_footer','mpl_add_js_login');
```

**Username checkup:**

```
function mpl_check_username() {

  $response = array();
    $username = sanitize_text_field($_POST['register_name']);
    if(username_exists($username)){
        $response['status'] = 'unavailable';
    $response['text'] = __('Username unavailable');
    }else{
         $response['status'] = 'available';
     $response['text'] = __('Username available');
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_username', 'mpl_check_username');
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'mpl_check_username');
```

**ERROR:** This code always turns to `$response['status'] = 'available';`even, if you type `admin` as username. Is there something wrong with the username_exists(); function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're POSTing `user_name` but in your code you're checking for `register_name`, you should instead check `$_POST['user_name']` instead.

You should also be checking to make sure a value is actually being passed as well, this is how I would do it instead (setting unavailable as default):

```
function mpl_check_username() {

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'unavailable',
        'text' => __( 'Username unavailable' )
    );

    $username = array_key_exists( 'user_name', $_POST ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_name'] ) : false;

    if ( $username && ! username_exists( $username ) ) {
        $response['status'] = 'available';
        $response['text']   = __( 'Username available' );
    }

    echo json_encode( $response );
    die();
}
```

All the `username_exists` function does is this code below:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
if ( $user ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
} else {
    $user_id = false;
}
```

You could also try this in your code to remove the possibility of the `username_exists` filter being used to return true for some weird reason.

Comment: Oh man thanks! Probably I replaced  user_name by register_name because my field has this name, but it doesn't make sense - cause it's the name of the passing parameter. Also is there a way to make the response faster? Or is this limited by my hosting?

Comment: You could generate your own cache of all currently used usernames and set that in a javascript variable and then just check that (but that also means all your current usernames would be available in javascript which may not be a good idea).  What I would do instead is to add a debounce on the text input, that way you're not querying every single change/press, and say only make the query after 5 second debounce or something

Comment: Yea fortuitously I did this right away :D So now it's not spamming the howl time Also I made some changes to the JS it's now in a JS file and not inline - also I added a whole checkup system to it.